# Start and stop AJAX by selecting radio buttons

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a small form that only has two radio buttons.  To turn on automatic checking and one to disable it:

```
<form class="user-containter-form">
    <input type="radio" id="refreshOn" name="perCheck" value="on" checked="checked">Periodic Checking On<br>
    <input type="radio" id="refreshOff" name="perCheck" value="off" onclick="alert('hello');" onclick="getTweets()">Periodic Checking Off
</form>
```

And I have an AJAX request for the actual getting of info.

```
if(document.getElementById('refreshOn').checked) {

    setInterval(function () {sendRequest()}, 2000);

    function sendRequest(){
        var xmlhttp;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
               if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
                   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
               } else if(xmlhttp.status == 400) {
                  alert('There was an error 400')
               } else {
                   alert('something else other than 200')
               }
            }
        }


        xmlhttp.open("GET","getTweets.php?",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

}
```

By default I have it set to on, but I would like the user to be able to disable to refresh.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your html become:

```
 <input type="radio" id="refreshOff" name="perCheck" value="off" onclick="disableAutoRefresh();" onclick="getTweets()">Periodic Checking Off
```

You declare new variable global and define new function:

```
var autoRefresh = true
function disableAutoRefresh(){
    autoRefresh = false;
}
```

You modify your code

```
if(document.getElementById('refreshOn').checked) {
    setInterval(function () {if (autoRefresh) sendRequest()}, 2000);
    //rest of your code
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set the interval to a variable and clear the variable based on user input

```
var theInterval;

if(document.getElementById('refreshOn').checked) {

    theInterval = setInterval(function () {sendRequest()}, 2000);

    function sendRequest(){
        var xmlhttp;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
               if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
                   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
               } else if(xmlhttp.status == 400) {
                  alert('There was an error 400')
               } else {
                   alert('something else other than 200')
               }
            }
        }


        xmlhttp.open("GET","getTweets.php?",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

}
$('input').click(function(){
  if(document.getElementById('refreshOff').checked){
    clearInterval(theInterval);
  }
});
```